# Which design pattern best suits for my scenario

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm still junior into programming, and would like to use best practices for my current project.

- I have checkout with checkout data.
- Shipping will be calculated based on products (quantity, weight) and shipping address.
- I have multiple shipping providers.
- At first I want to use `ShippingProvider 1` to calculate shipping price.
- If shipping can't be calculated I want to use `ShippingProvider 2`
- Again, if shipping can't be calculated I want to use `ShippingProvider 3`
- At the end if none of the providers respond with shipping I want to use fixed shipping set in database.

I was thinking about `Strategy pattern` but in my case it can be run all of the strategies during checkout. Do you have any ideas how can be done in the correct way?

Comment: You don't want to think too abstractly, you'll lose touch with the problem. Let's get some specifics. What programming language are you using, and what frameworks, if any? What does your existing code look like? What are "shipping providers" -- Functions? Classes? External processes? Remote servers?

Comment: Language is Python. For now there is only fixed shipping rate - pretty much hardcoded in the code. There is no functions and classes for the shipping. Providers will be external API calls to them. Thats why I would like to do this correctly if I can do this from scratch.